# Why can't component update when it is bound to an Array via v-model?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

`Array1` [image: and] `Array` area both bound to the same Array variable via v-model. But  when Array1 is updated, Array2 is NOT updated! So why?

Execution:

As you can see in the logs, `ArrayInput#1` has emitted `input` event. However, `updated` method of `ArrayInput#2` is not called. So why?

Source code is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/h313j5sh/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the passed props: `value` as following:

```
watch:{
  value: function(val){
     this.text = val.join(',')
  }
}
```

and also use v-model in the component:

```
template: '<input type="text" @input="onInputText" placeholder="Enter comma separated array" v-model="text" />',
```

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h313j5sh/7/

[Updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) block in not working as it's scope is limited till it's own component only, it will not affect DOM of other component.

Comment: Thanks. The `updated` is quite difference from what I thought it should be.